# Core Data - Assign values in one-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, relationship, nsfetchrequest

I'll post some code then explain what I need.

Two models:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class TrainingDay: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var day: String
    @NSManaged var trainingDetails: NSSet

}
```

and

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class TrainingDetails: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var exerciseName: String
    @NSManaged var repsNumber: String
    @NSManaged var setsNumber: String
    @NSManaged var trainingDay: TrainingDay

}
```

OK, now I have these methods here:

```
    func appendTrainingDay() {
        let dayLabel = dayName.text
        let dayEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TrainingDay", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
        let newTrainingDay = TrainingDay(entity: dayEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
        newTrainingDay.day = dayName.text

        var error: NSError?
        moc?.save(&error)

        if let err = error {
            var status = err.localizedFailureReason
            println("\(status)")
        } else {
            println("Training day:\(dayName.text)")
    }
}
```

and

```
   func appendTrainingDetailsToArray () {
        let nameLabel = exerciseName.text
        namesArray.append(nameLabel)
        let numberOfSets = setsNumber.text?.toInt()
        setsArray.append(numberOfSets!)
        let numberOfReps = repsNumber.text?.toInt()
        repsArray.append(numberOfReps!)


        let detailsEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TrainingDetails", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
        let trainingdetails = TrainingDetails(entity: detailsEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
        trainingdetails.exerciseName = exerciseName.text
        trainingdetails.setsNumber = setsNumber.text!
        trainingdetails.repsNumber = repsNumber.text!

        var error: NSError?
        moc?.save(&error)

        if let err = error {
            var status = err.localizedFailureReason
            println("\(status)")
        } else {
            println("Training day:\(trainingdetails)")
            println("Exercise: #\(exerciseName.text) saved successfully!")
            println("Number of sets: #\(setsNumber.text) saved successfully!")
            println("Number of reps: #\(repsNumber.text) saved successfully!")
        }
    }
```

And they are triggered here:

```
@IBAction func fixDayButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        appendTrainingDay()
    }


    @IBAction func doneButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        appendTrainingDetailsToArray()
        exerciseTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

With this done, what it was supposed to do is: the user will print a day, like "monday", save it into core data and, for that specific day, the user will add many detail objects as he wants, which will populate a tableView. Each of these objects contains 3 attributes: "exerciseName", "repsNumber" and "setsNumber". What seems that is happening is instead of creating a single "monday" object, for example, and add many details objects to this already existing one, I create many "mondays" and for each "monday", I create one detail object.

How can I fix this? 
How can I, inside the method that will save the details in core data, make a fetch for that specific day that I want and populate it with as many objects as I want?

-> I already set the one-to-many relationship and inverse between them.

-> I don't know how to make a proper fetch request with predicates matching what I want to search.

-> I'm new to Swift and have only a little experience with C++.

If someone could explain to me how to do this with examples, I would be very, very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `trainingdetails.trainingDay` relationship.  Unless I missed something you never set this relationship anywhere.

EDIT:

Something like this:

```
trainingdetails.trainingDay = selectedTrainingDay
```

To access the `trainingdetails` you simply fetch the day from Core Data and do something like this:

```
foreach( TrainingDetails trainingDetails in selectedTrainingDay.trainingDetails) {
   // Do stuff with the trainingDetails

}
```

Without a better understanding of the UI and workflows I am just guessing here.  Usually this kind of thing would have two UITableViews - one that lists the days, and when you select a day you go to another that lists the days trainingDetails.  In your case I am guessing you have a calendar view and when you select a day from the calendar view you present a list of trainingDetails for the selected day.

Comment: But where should I set it ? Right below trainingdetails.repsNumber = repsNumber.text! line? If so, how should I recover the day in which this attributes will be assigned to?